# What's wrong with this SSL Handshake Client Hello record?

Tags: ssl

I'm trying to implement SSL 3.0 "by hand" using windows socket (I know that openSSL & MS SSL API are out there but I just do want to do it for fun & to learn it from the inside view)

The first message (record) that I use to start a new SSL session, the very first TCP-message I send to a SSL Server (real server, like https://yahoo.com:443) is exactly like this (in hex) :

```
"16 03 00 00 19 01 00 00 15 03 00 bb 80 f3 8c 5d db f7 6c 94 56 d8 34 7a b5 9d 02 00 39 00"

Explanation:

16          //-- (22 in decimal) SSL3_RT_HANDSHAKE
03 00       //-- version : 3.0
00 19       //-- length of record excluding 5 bytes of header
01          //-- SSL3_MT_CLIENT_HELLO
00 00 15    //-- length of the following data
03 00       //-- SSL version 3.0
bb 80 f3 8c 5d db f7 6c 94 56 d8 34 7a b5 9d 02 00   //---- Random 16 bytes
39          //-- TLS_DHE_RSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA
00          //-- Compression method : none
```

But the server responses to me (in decimal) :

```
21-3-0-0-2-2-40
```

By [this](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/tpfhelp/current/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.ztpf-ztpfdf.doc_put.cur/gtps5/s5rcd.html) references, I know that the SSL handshake protocal failed without any clue about the reason.  What has gone wrong?

Comment: @EJP : I'm not trying to implement all respects of SSL, just V3.0 with AES_128 & SHA512 only. No CA(self-sign), no session, no re-negotiation, ..etc  I hope that's not too ambitious?

Comment: You will learn alot about SSL no matter where this journey ends. Reimplenting SSL from scratch is big, complex and ambitious, but you scoped it as small as can be. Implement what you can, and keep going until it is not fun anymore.

Comment: Thanks @ixe013, you inspired me. I will keep forwarding till it's not fun anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are [3 hard things in our craft](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html) :

1. Naming things
2. Cache invalidation
3. Off-by-one errors

Your 16 bytes of data is actually **17** bytes, making the "Lenght of following data" off-by-one in the header.

```
 $ xxd data.dat
 0000000: bb80 f38c 5ddb f76c 9456 d834 7ab5 9d02  ....]..l.V.4z...
 0000010: 00                                       .

 $ wc -c data.dat
 17 data.dat
```

The trailing `00` in your random data looks like a culprit to me.

If I may add, you can test your implementation with openssl, if only to compare what you send to what it sends (that's how I proceeded myself to find this). Use the `-ssl3` and `-debug` flags of the `s_client` function, like this :

```
 openssl s_client -connect yahoo.com:443 -ssl3 -debug
```

The openssl I use (my own build of 1.0.1c on Windows XP) sends more data than you do but it could come in handy.

```
 Loading 'screen' into random state - done
 CONNECTED(00000724)
 write to 0xac7fc0 [0xad1abb] (152 bytes => 152 (0x98))
 0000 - 16 03 00 00 93 01 00 00-8f 03 00 52 58 68 2c 6f   ...........RXh,o
 0010 - 3b 22 89 66 14 e5 c4 fa-14 81 43 e6 48 31 a4 74   ;".f......C.H1.t
 0020 - 96 67 6f a1 86 d0 08 8f-ef 1e bc 00 00 68 c0 14   .go..........h..
 0030 - c0 0a c0 22 c0 21 00 39-00 38 00 88 00 87 c0 0f   ...".!.9.8......
 0040 - c0 05 00 35 00 84 c0 12-c0 08 c0 1c c0 1b 00 16   ...5............
 0050 - 00 13 c0 0d c0 03 00 0a-c0 13 c0 09 c0 1f c0 1e   ................
 0060 - 00 33 00 32 00 9a 00 99-00 45 00 44 c0 0e c0 04   .3.2.....E.D....
 0070 - 00 2f 00 96 00 41 00 07-c0 11 c0 07 c0 0c c0 02   ./...A..........
 0080 - 00 05 00 04 00 15 00 12-00 09 00 14 00 11 00 08   ................
 0090 - 00 06 00 03 00 ff 01                              .......
 0098 - <SPACES/NULS>
```

A quick way to decode your payload in real time is to watch it through [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

You could also test your implementation against `s_server`. With your client and an openssl server to which you have the key, you could [provide Wireshark with the server's key](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL) and see *inside* the encrypted traffic in real time.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try a tour observing openSSL's debug mode. But does OpenSSL explain to me which part of the record is what? Do you have any documentation that explain me the SSL record format with **examples** other than the long,boring & abstract RFC?

Comment: There are a few out there, but RFC and source code are usually right and tested. So I usually stick to it, reading it slowly over and over. It will make sense in the end.

Comment: Wireshark is your friend for decoding what you send. I mentionned it in my answer, with a link to the SSL page.

Comment: I've read RFC once more & changed my code to a decent form. But things still doesn't work. I think I need a home tutor. Wireshark helped me to watch the traffic only, but it doesn't tell me what is what in SSL record. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Thanks @ixe013, I found da way to analyze SSL record with WireShark. You're genius ! So, the solution for my question is : WIRESHARK.

Comment: This might be helpful - TLS bytes explained https://tls13.ulfheim.net/